# how to save multiple json object in array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

hey guys i have json object. And i want to story many json object in array. I mean i want save patients info in a json object. It is working. But i can't save multiple patient info in a json object. Should i insert my json object in array?

```
    let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: para, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

    jsonString = NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String

    print(jsonString)

    do {
        let SavedPatient = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
        print("SavedPatient \(SavedPatient)")
        if let arrJSON = SavedPatient["contacts"] {
            for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
                let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
                print("object in array \(aObject)")
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }

    let utf8str = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    if let base64Encoded = utf8str?.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    {
        let encodedData = NSData(base64Encoded: base64Encoded, options:NSData.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue:0))
        //let data = encodedData
        if encodedData != nil {
            //write
            encodedData?.write(toFile: "\(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])/offline", atomically: true)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `JSON` also you are getting this JSON on server request?

Comment: Not here in comment add response in your question, also is this full response because there is nothing here `contacts` that you have added in your question.

Comment: how can i save array to phone directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store them in an array, but it would be a lot clearer if you defined a `struct` or `class` for your `Patient` type, set its properties using the JSON data, and then stored `Patient` objects in an array.

For example, a `Patient` struct:

```
struct Patient {
    var lastName: String?
    var firstName: String?
    // etc.
}
```

And initialize an array to store patients in:

```
var patients = [Patient]()
```

Then, when you read each JSON object, create a `Patient`:

```
var lastName = aObject["lastName"]    // or whatever your JSON field is named
var firstName = aObject["firstName"]  // or whatever your JSON field is named
var patient = Patient(lastName: lastName, firstName: firstName /*, etc. */)
```

And stick it in the array:

```
patients.append(patient)
```

Note that I declared the struct's properties as `Optional`s.

Comment: How can i do it with struct? Please show me some example for using my code?

Comment: how can i save this patients array to ios documentDirectory? Please reply me :)